# Solution to $0= c_1 x+c_2 x \ln \left(\frac{1+x}{x} \right)+c_3 \ln\left(\frac{1+x}{x} \right)+c_4$

Tags: calculus, functions, approximation

We want to solve 
\begin{align}
0= c_1 x+c_2 x \ln \left(\frac{1+x}{x} \right)+c_3 \ln\left(\frac{1+x}{x} \right)+c_4
\end{align}
for $x \in [0,1]$
 and where $c_1,c_2,c_3,c_4$ are non-zero constants.

Here are some alternative way of re-writing this equation:
\begin{align}
0&=x+a_1x \ln \left(\frac{1+x}{x} \right)+a_2ln \left(\frac{1+x}{x} \right)+a_3\\
1&=e^x+\left(\frac{1+x}{x} \right)^{a_1x}+\left(\frac{1+x}{x} \right)^{a_2}+e^{a_3}
\end{align}

I know that equations of this type generally don't have nice close form solutions.  **However, can we give at least an interval where the solution should be, that is if $x^*$ is an solution can we come up with $n$ and $m$ such that**
\begin{align}
0 \le n \le x^* \le m \le 1
\end{align}

I am also interested in the case when:
\begin{align}
c_2 \ge 0, \
c_3 \le 0, \
c_4 \ge 0
\end{align}
and $c_1$ can be either positive or negative.

Thank you for any help

Comment: Can you prove that this equation has always a solution? Might useful to consider the [Intermediate value theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intermediate_value_theorem)

Comment: I think that the correct range should be $x\in (0, 1]$ otherwise the equation becomes impossible.

Comment: @KimPeekII yes, you are right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Choose a point $a \in [0, 1]$ and because of the small range, use Series solution for $x-a$:

$$\ln\left(\frac{1+x}{x}\right) = \ln\left(1 + \frac{1}{a}\right) + \frac{(x-a)}{a(1+a)} + \frac{1+2a}{a^2(1+a)^2}\frac{(x-a)^2}{2} + \cdots $$

Then you may suppose $x-a$ is really small and stop to first order.

Notice that you might write the very first term as $A$, a constant.